# video.js: localhost works but does not play back from server

Tags: video.js

Set up the player in visual studio using IE8 and it worked flawlessly when running from localhost.

But when I copied the pages and video to my web server - no changes at all - the player doesn't work at all.  No controls are visible - get the "play button" square outline, but no details and nothing functions.

the test site i built is a simple page with only a player, code below, and I have made 0 changes to any of the config files.

Any ideas why this works locally but not when accessed from my web server?

```
    <link href="video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="video-js/video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js/video-js.swf" </script>

    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"

    controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"

    data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>

    <source src="big_buck_bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4'  />

</video>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in your browser's dev tools? As you've stated the problem isn't with the code but with this particular server, a link would be useful here.

Comment: No errors at all, and it was definitely a server issue.  This is a private server on an intranet and evidently I was the first person in our company to mess with .mp4 files on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer over the weekend.

It turns out there was no MIME type on the server associated to the .mp4 extension so IIS just ignored it.

Once I added the proper MIME type on the server then everything worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number of pathing issues. How do you export it to the web server? By physically uploading them yourself? Or via visual studio? Visual studio can sometimes alter the paths without you being aware. If you want a sure fire way of getting this working, my player code zip folder on my page will work anywhere. Simply plonk the extracted files on a web server and it will work = http://www.andy-howard.com/recreate-bbc-iplayer/index.html

Comment: Simple copy/paste on a privately owned machine.  See answer above; it was as simple as the web server not having a MIME type associated to the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and since I could not edit my company's server's .htaccess file (which was most certainly the problem) I, instead, uploaded my videos to a place like dropbox, got the public link and pulled my videos from there rather than my server.  This worked as an alternative solution.

```
<source src="https://YOURDROPBOXLINK..." type="video/mp4" />
```